# React Router loges me back to login component

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes, router

while I am logged in to different components and i am doing  http://localhost:3000/auth/login  it is redirecting me to login page how ever it should redirect to localhost:3000/ page

it should not take me to login component when i am already logged in on this section

Comment: Provide more information.

Comment: function Protected({ children }) {
  let auth = Cookies.get("token");
  if (!auth) {
    return <Navigate to="/auth/login" replace />;
  }

  return children;
}

Comment: const LoginUser = async () => {
   
      Cookies.set("token", token);

      if (response.status === 200) {


        navigate("/", { replace: true });
        setLoader(false)



        toast.success("User Authenticated");

      }

      GetUserInformation(token);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 400) {
        toast.error("Incorrect Password");
      } else {
        toast.error("Error");
      }
      setLoader(false);
    }
  };

Comment: Understand first if you are not able to provide much information then there is no possible way I can answer this. Edit the question and added proper code snippets or code.